# 2023 Developer Survey: no absolute values in 'Admired and Desired'?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2023

Link: https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-admired-and-desired-programming-scripting-and-markup-languages

Wouldn't it make sense to show the absolute values in the tooltips, like before? The ratio of users of a language that want to use it again is interesting, but knowing the number of users too gives a better idea of the overall popularity.

There's also a problem with this sentence:

- '*Rust is a language that generates **for** desire to use it once you get to know it **than** JavaScript*'.

I think it should be:

- '*Rust is a language that generates more desire to use it again than Javascript*'.