# Developer survey 2023: Hard to understand (or wrong?) sentence. Feedback

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2023

I think my English skills are very decent, but I have trouble understanding a sentence that came up in the explanation for the new "Admired and Desired" of the [2023 developer survey](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/):

> Rust is a language that generates for desire to use it once you get to know it than JavaScript.

Let's not discuss if this sentence might after all be correct or not, but:

It would be nice if the answers to this questions could suggest better ways to phrase this sentence or explain what is actually meant here.

Comment: Related: [2023 Developer Survey: no absolute values in 'Admired and Desired'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425488/2675154)

Comment: I have spoken English since infancy - over four decades - and even I'm not sure what the author of that sentence meant.

Comment: "Rust is a language that generates desire to use it once you get to know it. JavaScript Sux.".

Comment: Maybe Rust has particularly fancy `for` loops and therefore generates a  `for` desire?

Comment: i'd guess it's just weirdness from trying to convert from dreaded/loved to desired/admired while still misusing the results in the same way.

Comment: Strong "Why do they call it oven..." vibes

Comment: Perhaps the text in question was written on a phone with predictive text

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think this is a typo, and "for" should be "more":

> Rust is a language that generates more desire to use it once you get to know it than JavaScript.

(Even then, it doesn't quite make sense: the "more" has to do double duty, as both "more ... once you get to know it" and "more ... than JavaScript".)

The sense is a bit clearer including the whole sentence:

> For example, we can see JavaScript, our most used programming language since 2011, has a relatively short distance between admired and desired (<10 percentage points), while Rust, a top choice for developers who want to use a new technology for the past 8 years, shows a wide distance (>60 percentage points); Rust is a language that generates for desire to use it once you get to know it than JavaScript.

To rephrase the whole thing into bullets rather than one long sentence (six commas, two pairs of parentheses, and one semicolon, but no full stop!):

- JavaScript is our most used programming language since 2011
- JavaScript shows a relatively short distance between admired and desired: less than 10 percentage points
- Rust has been a top choice for developers who want to use a new technology for the past 8 years
- Rust shows a wide distance between admired and desired: more than 60 percentage points
- **We conclude that the more you get to know Rust, the more you want to use it; but this is less true for JavaScript**

Comment: Re *"into bullets"*: That may depend on the style guide in use, but it is supported by *[The Chicago Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)*, 6.122 (my emphasis): *"Lists that require typographic prominence,* ***that are relatively long,*** *or that contain items of several levels ... should be set vertically"*

Comment: Data and text make sense in this way. I think this is it - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I am all but infamous for my lack of grammar abilities. However, I believe in this case, one sentence was the wrong choice. I’m sure some grammar friendly people will be appalled at my efforts, but I think..

> Rust is a language that generates a desire to use it more once you
> get to know it, rather than using JavaScript.

Comment: I removed the one comma so it flows slightly better, but the "rather than using JavaScript" bit remains a weirdly random thing to say :) I would more think "as apposed to when you're using JavaScript" or something. Some kind of point to be made.

Comment: totally.  However, the original is more like a random word generator had at it.

Comment: I like this take.

Answer (score 2):

My personal interpretation - assuming that "for" should be "more" - is that

> Rust is a language that, compared to JavaScript, generates more desire to use it once you get to know it

In other words, a developer with equivalent experience in Rust and JavaScript would prefer to use Rust.